# Doing a FIFO with a queue of 2

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a queue which prioritize the first object in the queue that should max contain two objects. By doing this I'm using java.util.Queue and everytime a key is pressed it adds the key pressed as a string in the queue by doing q.add(). That's how far I know what to do.

My question is, how do I make it so that the queue only can contain two objects and that if I hold down space for example it doesn't add multiple spaces to the queue?

I'm using KeyEvent and KeyListener to take the input of the keys. By "only containing two objects." I mean that it should only contain two at a time, for example:

- this is the queue at the beginning : `[Space, Enter]` (Enter being the last key pressed),
- if I press the key P for example the oldest key should disappear and the newest should move the entire queue one step like this: `[P, Space]`.
- If I press enter now the Space should disappear and it should look like this: `[Enter, P]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do what you want:

```
if (! qFIFO.contains(key)) {
    qFIFO.add(key);
    if (qFIFO.size() >= 3) {
        qFIFO.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figuered out that i could use this below to make the size of the queue max 2 the only thing i don't know how to do is how to make it so you can't hold down a key and it will spam.

```
if(qFIFO.size() == 3){
     qFIFO.remove();
}
```